# Xamarin screen rotate (OnSizeAllocated)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using event `OnSizeAllocated` to check page's `width` or `height` on screen rotate.

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);                
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("width " + width);         
}
```

And each output looks like:

```
width 375
width 375
width 812
width 812
```

How can I limit the output to last string?

```
width 812
```

Comment: What do you mean by "limit" the output? Since the method will be invoked multiple times each time the screen is being rotated, the output consists of multiple lines.

Comment: @Csharpest For each screen rotate I have output with 4 strings. But I need only the last one to check it with 'If' statement

Comment: if you are sure its always 4 times, then create an int outside of the method `int onSizeAllocatedCount`. then in OnSizeAllocated u add `onSizeAllocatedCount++; if(onSizeAllocatedCount == 4) { WriteLine("width " + width); onSizeAllocatedCount = 0; }`

Comment: @Csharpest Thank you, it works but in my case I am getting the first result instead of last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only care about the update when the size actually changes the value, in this case between the second and third execution. What you then can do is to store the size in a field and compare it when `OnSizeAllocated` executes:

```
private double _width;
private double _height;

public MainPage
{
   _width = this.Width;
   _height = this.Height;
}

protected override void OnSizeAllocated( double width, double height )
{
   if ( _width != width || _height != height )
   {
       _width = width;
       _height = height;
       if ( width > height ) ScreenRotatedToLandscape( width, height );    
       //if ( height < width ) ScreenRotatedToPortrait( width, height);
   }
}

private void ScreenRotatedToLandscape( double newWidth, double newHeight )
{
    //your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Yes, but with a small addition. I need to catch event only on screen rotate to landscape (horizontal) orientation.

Comment: I have updated my code to take this into consideration :-)

Comment: Martin, thank you, it works! If it possible 1 more question. If in future i will need to add `if ( width < height ) ScreenRotatedToPortrait( width, height )` to this `OnSizeAllocated` event  i will get both output `ScreenRotatedToLandscape` and `ScreenRotatedToLandscape` on each screen rotate. How I can get output for landscape rotate only `ScreenRotatedToLandscape` output and for portrait rotate only `ScreenRotatedToPortrait`?

Comment: I have updated my code with an example. If you add an `if` to both cases, only one of them will be executed each time. Because width must be either bigger or smaller than height, not both at the same time

Comment: Martin, I just checked, in output I have both results. If I rotate from landscape to portrait  `<<ScreenRotatedtoPortrait>>
WIDTH 320
HEIGHT 536
<<ScreenRotatedToLandscape>>
WIDTH 568
HEIGHT 288`
and if i rotate from portrait to landscape `<<ScreenRotatedToLandscape>>
WIDTH 568
HEIGHT 256
<<ScreenRotatedtoPortrait>>
WIDTH 320
HEIGHT 504`
. It happens because on each rotate before `if (width > height )` statement output is `WIDTH 320
HEIGHT 536
WIDTH 568
HEIGHT 288` (before rotate and after it). This is a reason why both cases executed. How I can fix it ?

Comment: Can you post just the values of parameters of the `OnSizeAllocated` method? I'm interested in the order of values you get on each of the rotations. I think the first if check should avoid calling the same values again, so I am surprised.

Comment: Martin, this is result by `Debug.WriteLine(width + "/" + height)`. Rotated to landscape output `320/536   320/536   568/288 
  568/288`. Rotated to portrait output `568/256   568/256   320/504 
  320/504`.